# Cloudfront throw 403 on redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have a Lambda Edge attached to the Origin Request event that should handle redirects. The code is pretty simple, it checks if the requested URL is in a DynamoDB Table, and if so it returns a 301 response with the redirect URL.
This is the Lambda Edge code I have

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const uri = request.uri;

  let redirect = await getRedirect(uri);
  if (redirect) {
    const redirectResponse = createRedirect(redirect.To);
    callback(null, redirectResponse);
    return;
  }
  callback(null, request);
  return request;
};

function getRedirect(uri) {
  let params = {
    TableName: "Redirects",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#from = :from",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#from": "From"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":from": uri
    }
  };
  return dynamoDB
    .query(params)
    .promise()
    .then(result => result.Items[0])
    .catch(reject => null);
}

function createRedirect(uri) {
  const response = {
    status: "302",
    statusDescription: "Found",
    headers: {
      "cache-control": [
        {
          key: "Cache-Control",
          value: "max-age=0"
        }
      ],
      location: [
        {
          key: "Location",
          value: uri
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  return response;
}
```

If I test the Lambda Function using the test events I get the redirect response. However when I try to get the redirect using CloudFront I get a 403 error. So, suppose that URL `/a` should redirect to `/b`. If I call `cloudfront.url/a` I should get a message saying that the object has been moved to `/b` (or even better being redirected automatically). Instead I get the 403 error. Is there something wrong with the Lambda or I need to attach some permissions to CloudFront to get redirects working?

Comment: Can you provide more detailed output of the HTTP request that should cause the redirect (e.g by running `curl cloudfront.url/a`)? Are you sure that the Lambda@Edge is in effect triggered (e.g. by verifying the CloudWatch Logs)?

Comment: If I do a curl to a URL that has to be redirected I get this
`<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>A54C5423D45B705D</RequestId><HostId>I/9weyFZv8fG3rSbg2jfNQDhA11VBV8RlUyfGkuMtdNb8iV3vBCG6q7Jk2s9FO2cKgKLVlMRRPU=</HostId></Error>`
And yes, the Lambda is hit since I can see the request logs being created with the correct timestamps

Comment: In that case, your Lambda@Edge function is not returning the redirect (`curl URL` doesn't automatically follow redirects). You can add some debug statements in the `getRedirect()` function to figure out why. `console.log()` will end up in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Interesting: on Cloudwatch it says the Lambda role did not have the permissions to do queries on DynamoDB. However the role has the Query permission, and also as I said if I use the test events it does the query. Only from CloudFront it somehow looses permissions.
EDIT: I gave the Lambda Role all permissions for DynamoDB and it didn't changed

Comment: Can you verify you are hitting the right region? Lambda@Edge runs in the region of the CloudFront server, which is not (necessarily) the region your DynamoDB table is in. It's better to explicitly specify the region in Lambda@Edge code.

Comment: I've added this on top of the Lambda code
`aws.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });`
But I'm now getting a "Resource not found" error in cloudwatch. So it looks like is not hitting the us-east-1 DynamoDB endpoint, although I specified this

Comment: Ok, I'm dumb. I've added the region configuration to the DynamoDB client instance and it worked
`const dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-1" });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Niobos help I figured out what was the issue. The issue was with the DynamoDB region. My Lambda Edge function runs on eu-central-1, which is the closest edge to my location, but DynamoDB table is in us-east-1. So I changed my code to this and everything worked :)

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamoDB = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const uri = request.uri;

  let redirect = await getRedirect(uri);
  if (redirect) {
    const redirectResponse = createRedirect(redirect.To);
    callback(null, redirectResponse);
    return;
  }
  callback(null, request);
  return request;
};

function getRedirect(uri) {
  let params = {
    TableName: "Redirects",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#from = :from",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#from": "From"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":from": uri
    }
  };
  return dynamoDB
    .query(params)
    .promise()
    .then(result => result.Items[0])
    .catch(reject => null);
}

function createRedirect(uri) {
  const response = {
    status: "302",
    statusDescription: "Found",
    headers: {
      "cache-control": [
        {
          key: "Cache-Control",
          value: "max-age=0"
        }
      ],
      location: [
        {
          key: "Location",
          value: uri
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  return response;
}
```